# hiding frames in frameset using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frames

My requirement is to have multiple frames with each frame border having an icon to hide and show  the frame on clicking the icon.
how can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little fiddle that does a very basic version of that. Hopefully enough to send you on the right path. http://jsfiddle.net/bAsBe/

Basically you can simply toggle a class on each frame when the toggle button is pressed, then the class set the hide or width to 0 (depending on the frame position)

In the example you can see where multiple frame interact with each other it get slightly more complicated as you need to adjust the other frame to use the free space created by another frame being minimized.

But as you know where the frame will be and how to access them you should be able to set conditions up for your interface.